# setCredentialTreatment is not available in SQLite

Tags: zend-framework, sqlite, frameworks, zend-auth

I ran into a strange error, I want to share it with you.

I had to convert my MySQL database to SQLite, which was actually a piece of cake with the program called DBConvert.

So I changed in my application.ini:

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/db_name.db"
```

And try to show my website, everything looks correct. Except when I try to login to my website, it gives the following error:
    The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.

Comment: Move everything below the line in your question to an answer, posted below. In 2 days, you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Because SHA is not supported by SqLite. Same thing with PostgreSQL and SHA1. So, it is not "fault" of ZF, but sqlite. So your question title could be more specific ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCredentialTreatment(SHA(?))` is not supported by SQLite.

Remove that setCredentialTreatment line, and change the following:

```
$authAdapter->setCredential(**sha1(**$password));
```